# How to make a textView stick to the same position on imageView background with different screen ratios

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

-I'm new to constraintlayout  and I want to constraint a textview in some specific places on imageView like in here

[image: [1]]

-I tried to use guidelines anchoring the text to them like this but it didn't show the same between different screen sizes

[image: [2]]

- so I need a way to connect the text to the image in way the text be all the time in the place I needed to be in different ratios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to anchor each of your views to the top and bottom of the page and then set the slider % to 25% and 75%. You can adjust the views that way so that they're always relatively similar in positioning no matter the screen size.

Comment: i used ratio in guidelines this time rather than the normal arrow and it worked!!! i don't know what the difference is but it did work :D thank you pal

Comment: No problem! Check off my answer as correct if you could! Glad I could help.